# Removing Headers from CSV using Windows Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, header

I have a CSV file which has several thousand lines, every 59 lines there are headers which I need to remove, but I am unsure on how to do this. From what I have read the Powershell tool is a good option but the commands I have found do not seem to work as Powershell keeps spitting out errors referring to 'Grep' not being found.

Please could I have some pointers?

Thanks

Comment: `grep` is not a powershell cmdlet but it can be used as an alias for `select-string`

Comment: If there is a common thing among these headers, try using `cat file.csv | Select-String -NotMatch "SomeCommon"`

Comment: Could you please post in the format of the csv file..? are you asking to simply remove every 59th line, or something more specific?

Comment: Many thanks for this, unfortunatley it isnt quite every 59th line, header is on the first, then the 60th and then its quite random after that (Inspected the file a bit closer). However, the header line I would like removing are all the same: Matter,Client,description etc etc. I woiuld only like to keep the first header and then pipe the results to a new CSV. (If its easier, all headers could be removed and I could just add the first line header manually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be really simple.

```
Get-Content $File -ReadCount 59 | ForEach{$_|Select -Skip 1}
```

That reads the file in groups of 59 lines, and skips the first one of each group. Then either pipe it to Out-File or assign that to a variable, or whatever it is you want to do.

Ok, if the header line is the same you can just Get-Content and filter for lines that don't match the first line, then add the header back in as you said. This will create a new file with only the first line, then copy the original to it, filtering out lines that match that first line that's in the new file.

```
$Header = Get-Content $File | Select -First 1
$Header | Out-File C:\NewFile.csv
Get-Content $file | Where{!($_ -Match $Header)}| Out-File C:\NewFile.Csv -append
```

Comment: Many thanks for this, unfortunatley it isnt quite every 59th line, header is on the first, then the 60th and then its quite random after that (Inspected the file a bit closer). However, the header line I would like removing are all the same: Matter,Client,description etc etc

Comment: Many thanks for this TMD, it almost worked, but after running the 2nd line I get the following symbol: >> and the new document only has the header in it. I have tried running the 2 scripts together and also individually, I must be doing something wrong?...

Comment: Sorry, I was missing a closing ) in my where statement. I have updated my answer to correct that. I was also evidently tired and had `Where(stuff)` when I should have had `Where{stuff}`. It should all be fixed, I even tested it on a mocked up file to make sure.

Comment: Absolutley superb, many thanks TMT!